# Difficulty in applying custom font in Android

Tags: android

I have both Custom Font example and a small List View example app. But I am unable to join them.

```
 /** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv);
    Typeface cFont = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/jcc.ttf");
    tv.setTypeface(cFont);


<TextView  
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:text="@string/hello"
android:textSize="18sp"
android:id="@+id/tv"
/>
```

and

```
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_product_list);

    String asim02 = System.getProperty("line.separator");

    String products[] = {
            "Product1" + asim02 +"Definition1", 
            "Product2" + asim02 +"Definition2",
            "Product3"+ asim02 +"Definition3", 
            "Product4"+ asim02 +"Definition4",  };

    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);

    // Adding items to listview
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, R.id.p_list,   products);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);



<TextView

        android:textColor="?android:textColorPrimary"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:id="@+id/p_list"
        />
```

How can I assign "@+id/p_list" and "@+id/tv" together?

Comment: You need to post the relevant code here, I'm afraid no one will download the zip

Comment: If you afraid of zip see the image here https://dl.dropbox.com/u/15065300/CustomFont.png

Comment: @DavidCaunt I have improved the files a lot. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to make custom adapter to set the data in your listview.
First concentrate on ListView only. Once you are able to display list in your app. Then in your adapter code Try to integrate custom font.

Comment: Did you able to find the adapter for the list ? In adapter there will be an object of text view. Now you just need to set the typeface method's value and its done. Its damn simple brother.

Comment: I believe you are in the right track. Please give me an adopter code. I am looking farrowed to you. Apologizing for disturbing you.

Comment: Download sample project from here. http://www.mediafire.com/?f45f2a6tt15k5un  Happy to help you :)

Comment: **BOSS** you are great! Your code working nice. As you are brilliant in contrast I am so dull. and that is the problem. I have a small search engine which could find my product data But this time (in your code) I am unable to setup the search engine properly. I am afraid of telling you to work for me more! But I will be very happy if you kindly help me once more. Rather then massive change in my app, Could you please change the adopter in my app? That I can search my product? Here is my full app http://www.mediafire.com/download.php?wcyi6yerfv4pns7 Thanks in advance

Comment: **BOSS** I have visited your website. One and only **Sonam Kapoor!**

Comment: I would like to help you. Right now I am bit busy in my social life. But search functionality is very simple. Put a EditText above listview. And add TextWatcher to it.http://android-helper.blogspot.in/2011/03/android-search-in-listview-example.html This is the simplest link which can be helpful